# Insignificant confounder

Tags: regression, finance

I have a simple regression of price on growth:

$price_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1growth_i+u_i$

In this simple regression, the p value for $\beta_1$ is highly significant, but I am worried that there is a confounder (Risk of the company). I found that the beta of the stock is correlated with both price and growth. I then controlled for it in a multivariate regression:

$price_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1growth_i + \beta_2beta_i+\nu_i$

The coefficient $\beta_1$ is still highly significant, but slightly less so than in the simple bivariate. The coefficient $\beta_2$ is not significant. Because of these results, I am worried that beta is a bad confounder. Is this the case?

Comment: You don't have a multivariate regression, you have a multiple or multivariable regression. Whether or not beta is a "good" confounder cannot be ascertained by looking at the coefficient or its p-value. Confounding is a result of the causal relationships between your observed and unobserved variables. Preferably, you should encode your knowledge about the causal structure in a DAG and base the confounders on that. See [this document](https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r493.pdf) for a concise overview.

Comment: Okay, thanks @COOLSerdash. Both price and growth in my model are based on, and use beta as an input somewhere in the process (Theoretically there should be a direct mathematical relationship between each). Would it help if I regressed each variable separately on beta? Based on the relationship between them, I would be inclined to then use beta despite the insignificance.